# Eclipse - build only java part and native part I will build with ndk-build tool

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

How to ASK eclipse to not build the Native part of the Android project? I mean when I press 'Run As->Android Application' Eclipse rebuilds the Native part, whereas I wanted to build from command line using 'ndk-build' each time with different options. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually just:

1. right click on project
2. select "Properties"
3. select "C/C++ Build"
4. Uncheck "Use default build command"
5. Clear the build command (so there's no text at all)
6. Click "Apply"

The result is that the build will run, but won't do any actual building and will be much faster.